# How to numbering this item in a table automatically?

Tags: tables, numbering

I am new for latex, and I have a question. If a table like can be numbering automatically.

Now I'm numbering item in a table by myself, like this:

```
\begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    1. prepare process \\ \hline
    (a) cut the infinite pipe into three regions,  \\
    (b) calculate the boundary velocity of the finite pipe using series expression, \\
    (c) decompose the fluid field into singular and harmonic parts, \\
    (d) solve the harmonic field and make the tables of strength $\bm{G}^i$, \\
    \midrule
    2. calculation process \\ \hline
    (a) interpolate $\bm{g}_2^i(\bm{x}_f)$ using $\bm{G}^i$, \\
    (b) resolve the Stokeslets $\bm{S}_{pipe}$. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{1 and 2 in relation to Foo and Bar.}
\end{table}
```

and It looks like this, 
[image]

Can the items in the table be indexing automatically in latex. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! it can be (partly) done by use of enumerate lists, however a code for table with list will be longer as it you have now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with use of `enumerate` lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\rule[-1ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item prepare process\\[1.5ex] 
    \hrule height0.3pt \relax
    \begin{enumerate}
\item cut the infinite pipe into three regions,  
\item calculate the boundary velocity of the finite pipe using series expression, 
\item decompose the fluid field into singular and harmonic parts, 
\item solve the harmonic field and make the tables of strength $\bm{G}^i$, 
    \end{enumerate}
\hrule height 0.5pt \relax
\item calculation process \\[1.5ex] 
    \hrule height0.3pt \relax
    \begin{enumerate}
\item interpolate $\bm{g}_2^i(\bm{x}_f)$ using $\bm{G}^i$, 
\item resolve the Stokeslets $\bm{S}_{pipe}$. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\rule[2ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
\caption{1 and 2 in relation to Foo and Bar.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
or simpler and nicer (to my taste):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\rule[-1ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item prepare process
    \begin{enumerate}
\item cut the infinite pipe into three regions,  
\item calculate the boundary velocity of the finite pipe using series expression, 
\item decompose the fluid field into singular and harmonic parts, 
\item solve the harmonic field and make the tables of strength $\bm{G}^i$, 
    \end{enumerate}
\item calculation process 
    \begin{enumerate}
\item interpolate $\bm{g}_2^i(\bm{x}_f)$ using $\bm{G}^i$, 
\item resolve the Stokeslets $\bm{S}_{pipe}$. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\rule[2ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
\caption{1 and 2 in relation to Foo and Bar.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]